# Redirect php form in a Fancybox

Tags: php, magento, fancybox

I'm using Magento and I have a custom form function (in my controller.php) and I want to redirect the user in a Fancybox when done.

This is my php code :

```
$this->_redirect('shop/myprofile');
```

Can I open this link in a Fancybox instead of a the main page ?

Or another way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to POST the data of your form in the fancybox you can use the ajax mode :

```
$("#a_id").fancybox({
        ajax : {
            type    : "POST",
            data    : 'mydata=test'
        }
    });
```

If you want to display the content of a full page inside of a fancybox, you can use the iframe mode :

```
<a id="a_id" href="shop/myprofile">profile</a>

$("#a_id").fancybox({
     'type' : 'iframe'
});
```

see API docs and examples at http://fancybox.net/blog

But your question isn't very understandable

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my problem is that I want to send a picture in my form, and I don't know how to do it in Magento with Ajax. So I want to have a classic form with a php redirection.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you need to use some ajax.

Something like this

```
$("#divid").load("shop/myprofile")
```